How to install aic8800FC wifi driver in Ubuntu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and my WiFi usb adapter came with a driver for Windows only (it's an aic8800FC). I tried multiple solutions:
Solution 1
I tried a to follow this blog: https://kanyi.gm/how-to-install-and-enable-aic8800-chipset-wi-fi-driver-for-linux/ But encountered an error:
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel:6.8.0-41-generic (x86_64)

Solution 2
I also tried to install drivers from GitHub by using the following commands:
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lynxlikenation/aic8800.git
cd aic8800/drivers/aic8800
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a

But this still didn't fix the problem (altough I didn't have any errors)
I must also admit that I'm not comfortable with installing from GitHub.

Check in terminal mokutil --sb as the driver can't load with Secure Boot enabled
